# How should I go about tracking down my stolen iPhone 6 using Find My iPhone?

Tags: find-my-iphone, iphone

I have used Find My iPhone to track down my iPhone 6.

It's running iOS 8 and the iCloud web app shows that someone has travelled a fair distance with it.

How should I go about protecting access to my data on the deviceas well as not ruin all chances of finding it.

My worry is sending a remote wipe will reduce the chance they can get my data but I won't be able to track the device further.

Answer (score 14):

1. Remote-Lock the phone so they can't use it.
2. Visit your local police.

Comment: This.  Once you perform step 1, they have an expensive yet useless brick.