# Can stolen iPhone still be tracked using Find My iPhone after restoring?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

My iPhone has just been stolen. The chances of the thief resetting is high but will still be locked to my iCloud.

If they reset it and connects to a Wi-Fi in hope it's not locked to iCloud will Find My iPhone tracking still work?

Comment: do NOT remote wipe your phone.  Log into icloud.com and set LOST MODE, which will lock it and allow you to display a lock screen message.  Do NOT pick REMOTE WIPE.

Comment: We have many questions similar to yours. Feel free to edit this to make it clear what specific part of the FMF you don't get (link to Apple's official descriptions / faqs) showing some research to have the best chance this will be reopened. Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179738/

Comment: After realizing that your iPhone has been stolen. Go to a computer as soon as possible . Point the Web browser to iCloud.com and log in using your Apple ID and password. Click on the "Find My iPhone" icon to initiate a search for your phone. Once your phone appears on the map, click on the "i" icon next to it. Click "Remote Lock" to stop anyone from using your phone

Answer (score 2):

You can't restore an iPhone which has active Find My iPhone using iTunes.
If the iPhone is restored outside of iTunes, then Activation Lock will be enabled and you can still track the device providing a SIM card is inserted or the device is connected to Wi-Fi.